# EMR Hudi cannot create hive connection jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, aws-glue, apache-hudi

Trying to save hudi table in Jupyter notebook with hive-sync enabled. I am using EMR: 5.28.0 with AWS Glue as catalog enabled:

```
# Create a DataFrame
inputDF = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("100", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:39.340396Z"),
        ("101", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T12:14:58.597216Z"),
        ("102", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:40.417052Z"),
        ("103", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:40.519832Z"),
        ("104", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-01T12:15:00.512679Z"),
        ("105", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-01T13:51:42.248818Z"),
    ],
    ["id", "creation_date", "last_update_time"]
)

# Specify common DataSourceWriteOptions in the single hudiOptions variable
hudiOptions = {
'hoodie.table.name': 'my_hudi_table',
'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': 'id',
'hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field': 'creation_date',
'hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field': 'last_update_time',
'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable': 'true',
'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table': 'my_hudi_table',
'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields': 'creation_date',
'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class': 'org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor'
}

# Write a DataFrame as a Hudi dataset
(inputDF.write
.format('org.apache.hudi')
.option('hoodie.datasource.write.operation', 'insert')
.options(**hudiOptions)
.mode('overwrite')
.save('s3://dytyniak-test-data/myhudidataset/'))
```

receiving the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling o309.save.
: org.apache.hudi.hive.HoodieHiveSyncException: Cannot create hive connection jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are following the [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hudi-work-with-dataset.html) from AWS documentation. I got it to work using Hudi 0.9.0 by setting `hive_sync.mode` to `hms` in `hudiOptions` (see [hudi docs](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/configurations/#hoodiedatasourcehive_syncmode)):

```py
hudiOptions = {
    'hoodie.table.name': 'my_hudi_table',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': 'id',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field': 'creation_date',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field': 'last_update_time',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable': 'true',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table': 'my_hudi_table',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields': 'creation_date',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class': 
    'org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.mode': 'hms'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to enable Hive in the list of applications in the cluster, and enable Hive integration with Glue Catalog:

[image]